# How to convert comma sepearted string value to display as a column name

Tags: sql, postgresql

In PostgreSQL, I have generated Comma separated string of required columns dynamically. But how to convert them as Column name ?

I have tried it in SQL Server.. got success but want to do in postgreSQL

My Comma Separated String as :
String_agg

```
7_headid,7_grade,8_headid,8_grade,6_headid,6_grade,5_headid,5_grade,4_headid,4_grade,3_headid,3_grade,15_headid,15_grade,9_headid,9_grade,1_headid,1_grade,2_headid,2_grade
```

Required Output as :

```
Column name -->    Sr.No || 7_headid || 7_grade || 8_headid || 8_grade || 6_headid ||6_grade || So on
-----------------------------------------------------------------------  
Rows value  -->      1         2          3           4            5         6         7
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 1 AS "Str. No"
     , 2 AS "7_headid"
     , 3 AS "7_grade"
     ...
```

You have to [double-quote identifiers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) like these violating basic rules.

Comment: You did not specify that in the question. Use dynamic SQL in a PL/pgSQL function and `EXECUTE`. Or a `crosstab()` function. Or cast to a predefined rowtype. It depends on the exact circumstances ...